Use Git-tfs to retrieve branches one by one
I'm getting migration loops/errors when trying to import an entire 12yo TFS repo that has renamed branches and only Sherlock Holmes knows what has been done to its structure.
I was wondering if it would be possible to migrate just the main, and then add some specific branches that are still under maintenance.
Did anyone manage such a scenario?
Thanks

May i know what's your TFS version? And how do you migrate the repo? Are you migrating TFS to git and then import the git repo? It's recommended to add some steps and log....etc to more precise. In addition, please check the github link if it helps.

Hello, sure the TFS version is 10.0.40219.1 I migrate the repo using git-tfs clone ..... $/main --branches=all --resumable -d . The issue that I've is that on a certain old branch it loops ( but my question was different) can I add branches after an initial git migration or not?

it's supported to add branches one by one via gittfs. Git and TFVC managed branches in different way. Please check the details below, thanks.

Yes, you can add branches one by one via gittfs.
For example, i have the TFVC repo as below:

Steps to checkout branches:

Migrate main branch firstly via command:

git-tfs clone http://tfs/DefaultCollection $/TFVC1/main --resumable -d

It create git repo main on local -> cd main to target repo -> the default branch is master, run git checkout -b main to create a main branch in repo.



Run git commands to push the branch to target git repo:

git remote add origin http://tfs/DefaultCollection/ProjectFromTFS/_git/ProjectFromTFS
git add .
git commit -m "test"
git push -u origin


The main branch has been created.

To create a new branch Releases, do the same step above, change main to Releases in the commands. When you push the Releases branch, use command git push --set-upstream origin Releases.

Git and TFVC managed branches in different way, now we have two git branches in git repo:

Edit:

let say that I've on TFS $/branches/b1 and $/branches/b2 that both inherits from $/main (now I'm simplifying) will this approach keep the relation between b1 and b2 on main for git repo?

You can migrate the main branch with --branches=all, it will checkout $b1, $b2 as well, but current branch name is still master.
 git-tfs clone http://tfs/DefaultCollection $/TFVC1/main --branches=all --resumable -d


Rename the master branch to main:
git branch -m master main

Then you can push to remote for main, b1, b2 one by one:
git push --set-upstream origin <targetbranch>


Check the branches, it has correct Behind|Ahead relations between main, b1, b2 branch. The relationship is kept.

Edit:
if --branches=all cannot be used due to the loop by a renamed branch, you have to follow the previous step, migrate the branch one by one: git-tfs clone http://tfs/DefaultCollection $/TFVC1/<branch> --resumable -d. The branches are mapped/tracked individually, will not keep relationship.

With --branches=all, it shows below which is different.


ok but in this case.. let say that I've on TFS $/branches/b1 and $/branches/b2 that both inherits from $/main (now I'm simplifying) will this approach keep the relation between b1 and b2 on main for git repo?

Yes, you can check all branches to local with --branches=all, then rename master to main, push the branches to remote git one by one, the history is kept between the branches. I edit the reply with details, thanks.

if I use --branches=all it will go in loop due to a renamed branch... so my goal was to download master then add all the others one by one. if possible

@advapi, if --branches=all cannot be used due to the loop by a renamed branch, you have to follow the previous step, migrate the branch one by one: git-tfs clone http://tfs/DefaultCollection $/TFVC1/<branch> --resumable -d, then push the target git repo. But the branches are individual tracked in this case, the relationship is not kept. I will edit the reply and share the difference between --branches=all and without --branches=all. thanks.
